# Installing Kali tools into UBUNTU 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation, kali-linux-tools

How can I install all the tools of Kali Linux in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? What are the sources of these tools?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://tools.kali.org/kali-metapackages

Comment: Generally speaking, if you are going to use these tools I advise you use Kali as generally speaking there are modifications, often to the kernel and system configuration, to enhance the use of these tools.