# Adding PGP key in Open Terminal

Tags: 14.04, pgp, kali

Trying to install Kali tools into UBUNTU 14.04. But couldn't figure out how to Add PGP key in Open Terminal as told here

[Installing Kali tools into UBUNTU 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608453/installing-kali-tools-into-ubuntu-14-04-lts?noredirect=1#comment854126_608453)

Can anyone please tell me how to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open an editor, eg. `gedit`.

Add the following text into a new file.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: SKS 1.1.4
Comment: Hostname: keyserver.ubuntu.com

mI0ET324YwEEANbSlISrOlAGjxgFRxiN6jk0JIl/vxQ8lapRdxZ4DHDAQdXbX4AuigMBkP5e
sOxhMpDnkgMRtEVpaBMdQheA0/431pPQYqkr3jdeZw5JS5opiyJ4qr/QrcoSFHSluEkWkbZ6
RYOkA25vW31KK2FB2LQVRYk580llXAVgIUznm2ATABEBAAG0GExhdW5jaHBhZCBQUEEgZm9y
IHdhZ3VuZ4i4BBMBAgAiBQJPfbhjAhsDBgsJCAcDAgYVCAIJCgsEFgIDAQIeAQIXgAAKCRAb
IuuNj9/bVxabBADSGN8cp+hqkdZqwq263wdz/UGsiuB1bCrH06/HznC/ZC5rjfH3aQ1Dwwag
zYCrSD3c0cKNAqD10009N76RMlzZBH8kKL9khH3zPL/k4/lYuVP7y6NKFbBsnawEUc0mWcCa
mH4ScTdWWPXP/mOQiUUjnQ1bZhzpcbQOb+hEUAqExg==
=fJ+8
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Save the file as `/<your_path>/kali.pgp`.

Perform the following command:

```
sudo apt-key add /<your_path>/kali.pgp
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It says

gpg: invalid radix64 character C2 skipped

gpg: invalid radix64 character AD skipped

gpg: invalid radix64 character C2 skipped

gpg: invalid radix64 character AD skipped

Comment: Try this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10820657/